# Double Quotes at the end of each line while writing from/to .CSV

Tags: python, sql, csv, double-quotes

Can anybody help me remove these double quotes at the start/end of each line ?

I have a large csv (800k rows) and want to create insert statements to get the data into a SQL DB. I know the code is really ugly but i've never used Python before... any help is greatly appreciated...

```
#Script file to read from .csv containing raw location data (zip code database)
#SQL insert statements are written to another CSV
#Duplicate zip codes are removed


import csv

Blockquote

csvfile = open('c:\Canada\canada_zip.csv', 'rb')
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.readline())
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
reader.next()

ofile  = open('c:\Canada\canada_inserts.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, dialect)

#DROP / CREATE TABLE
createTableCmd = '''DROP TABLE PopulatedPlacesCanada       \n\
CREATE TABLE PopulatedPlacesCanada                         \n\
(                                                  \n\
ID INT primary key identity not null,      \n\
Zip VARCHAR(10),                           \n\
City nVARCHAR(100),                        \n\
County nvarchar(100),                      \n\
StateCode varchar(3),                      \n\
StateName nvarchar(100),                   \n\
Country nvarchar(30),                      \n\
Latitude float,                            \n\
Longitude float,                           \n\
PopulationCount int,                       \n\
Timezone int,                              \n\
Dst  bit                                   \n\
)'''
writer.writerow([createTableCmd])

table = 'PopulatedPlacesCanada'
db_fields = 'Zip, City, County, StateCode, StateName, Country, Latitude, Longitude,         PopulationCount, Timezone, Dst'
zip_codes = set()

count = 0

for row in reader:
  if row[0] not in zip_codes: #only add row if zip code is unique
    count = count + 1
    zipCode = row[0] #not every row in the csv is needed so handpick them using row[n]
    city = row[1].replace("\'", "").strip()
    county = ""
    state_abr = row[2]
    state = row[3].replace("\'", "").strip()
    country = 'Canada'
    lat = row[8]
    lon = row[9]
    pop = row[11]
    timezone = row[6]
    dst = row[7]
    if dst == 'Y':
      dst= '1'
    if dst == 'N':
      dst = '0'
    query = "INSERT INTO {0}({1}) VALUES ('{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12})".format(table, db_fields, zipCode, city, county, state_abr, state, country, lat, lon, pop, timezone, dst)
    writer.writerow([query])
    zip_codes.add(row[0])
    if count == 100:  #Go statement to make sql batch size manageable
      writer.writerow(['GO'])
```

Answer (score 0):

2 pointers first:-
    1) Use triple inverted-commas for multi-line strings over triple apostrophe's.
    2) No need to put "\n\" in multi-line strings.

To remove quotes from a line, use python's regular expression module instead of string replacement.

```
import re
quotes = re.compile('^["\']|["\']$')
city = quotes.sub( row[3] )
state = quotes.sub( row[4] )
```

Or you'd use strip with the character you want to remove from both ends; only one char at a time AFAIK:-

```
city = row[3].strip('"').strip("'")
state = row[4].strip('"').strip("'")
```

Finally, don't use the csv module for file output, as it expects the 'context'. Just open the file, and write to it.

```
ofile = file( 'canada_inserts.sql','w' )
ofile.write( createTableCmd + '\n' )
for row in reader:
...
   ofile.write( query + '\n' )
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with removing the quotes using `replace` IMHO. Regular expressions actually are overkill here. The last part actually answers his question, but somewhat indirectly.

Comment: nothing wrong with replace, no, but the use of it was inefficient, as it searches every character in the line, rather than just the start and end characters, as was the described desired effect. I agree RE's are a bit overkill, but they are much more efficient for repeated text operations, when compiled in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing a *CSV* file. Don't use a csv writer for it, as it probably adds the additional ascaping to your data. Instead, use

```
ofile = file( 'load.sql', 'w')
# Raw write, no newline added:
ofile.write(...)
# or, with newline at the end:
print >>ofile, "foobar."
```

It's the CSV writer that is adding the quotes to your line: most CSV dialects expect strings to be wrapped in quotes when they contain certain characters, such as `,` or `;` or even spaces. However, as you are writing SQL and not CSV, you don't need or want this.